# Manage asyncio task

Tags: python-asyncio

I need a some asyncio's task manager.
Wrapper for create task:

```
    def create_task(self,
                    coro: Coroutine[Any, Any, Any],
                    timeout: Optional[int] = None) -> str:
    task_uuid = uuid()
    task = asyncio.create_task(
        asyncio.wait_for(coro, timeout)
    )
    return task.uuid
```

But I have to know when task is done and write info about it to Redis.
I see two variants:

1. Use `add_done_callback` but in that case I should pass not async function. But redis client is async. So:

```py
def task_done(self, task: asyncio.Task) -> 
    async def write_to_redis(params: dict) -> None:
        redis.write(...)  
    asyncio.create_task(write_to_redis)
```

2. Use wrapper for coro:

```py
    def create_task(self,
                     coro: Coroutine[Any, Any, Any],
                     timeout: Optional[int] = None) -> LTaskUuid:
        async def wrapper():
            try:
                await coro()
            finally:
                await redis.write(...)
        asyncio.create_task(
            asyncio.wait_for(wrapper(), timeout)
        )
        return task.uuid
```

Which approach is better? Or maybe there is another solution?

Comment: Both approaches look fine. The first one appears slightly simpler and works even if the task is created someone else, but it has a downside that it uses callbacks which can [lose exception causality](https://vorpus.org/blog/notes-on-structured-concurrency-or-go-statement-considered-harmful/). BTW both your examples seem to lack the assignment `task.uuid = task_uuid` or equivalent.

Comment: I didn't get what is "lose exception causality"?

Comment: Unhandled exceptions that happen in callbacks get dropped on the floor, while exceptions in a coroutine get propagated to the coroutine that awaits them. With callbacks there is no concept of "caller" or "awaiter" (the entity that _caused_ the callback, hence _causailty_), all callbacks are directly invoked by the event loop.

Comment: Could you post some example please?

Comment: If some exception will be invoked in done_callback it crashes all program? I right get you?

Comment: The problem is precisely that the program **doesn't** crash, even though there is no one to catch the exception. Instead, the exception traceback gets printed on stderr and the exception effectively gets ignored.

Comment: But if I wrap calling task.result() in callback with try: except block I can catch any exception that invoked in task?

Comment: You can make the two approaches equivalent, yes. My point about `add_done_callback` was more of a *general* advice to be careful with callbacks, not something that afflicts your code as shown.